# How to apply ifelse statement for list of data in R

Tags: r, data-analysis

I want to create a new list of data comparing whether the *predict* will be equal *actual*  in every row of the data in order to check for my correctly predicted outcome. sorry if my code is very messy and inefficient. I need some guideline for the problem stated below. thank you.

First i create a list for ***predict*** and ***actual***

```
 predict <-list(compare_result[,1])`

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27  
 1  1  0  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  0  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  0  0  

actual <-list(compare_result[,2])

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 
 0  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  1  1  0  0  0  1  0  1  1  0  0  0
```

Then i try to use the `ifelse`   statement for both of the list but an error came out:

```
> comapare2 <- ifelse(predict=actual,"true","false")

Error in ifelse(predict = actual, "true", "false") : 
  unused argument (predict = actual)
```

Comment: I don't know much about R but _if_ comparisons usually req the _==_ operator. i.e. `predict=actual` --> `predict == actual`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare two vectors directly, e.g.:

```
matches <- compare_results[, 1] == compare_results[,2]
```

and then if you need that to be a list (not sure why), just cast the final result:

```
matches_list <- as.list(matches)
```

Comment: thank you very much. Spend 1 hour solving it ,why didn't I think of that.